# How to Compare null value with some value in SQL?

Tags: sql

i have question about how can i compare the getting value is null and compare in if condition in sql like

here is my data `null` value bcz i have no data in custId when i use this query its right `Select custId from myTable where Id=123` but how to compare `null` to the value? also some time values in row show both condition applicable it mean some custId data available also update custId in ..query in this condition when it will be true

```
IF (Select custId from myTable where Id=@Id) != @custId 
BEGIN
    ...query
END
```

Comment: What shoulod "compare null with some value" mean? Please clarify your question. A value is null or is not null. You can't "compare" null with anything else.

Comment: Sample data and the desired result would help.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `[NOT] DISTINCT FROM`?

Comment: @JonasMetzler simply brother, ex. i have 3 entry in my table and there data Id is `1`,`2`,`3` and custId is like `123 ,291 ,null`  now in my condition `Select custId from myTable where Id=3` so my data i null so how can i use condition and it will be become a true in the sense parameter side custId is not null its  int value and i want to compare with difference if both are different then condition is true.. so what i do?

Comment: Can you use something like this:

IF (Select ISNULL(custId,-1) from myTable where Id=@Id) != ISNULL(@custId,-1) 
BEGIN
    ...query
END

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this code below will work? This accounts for both sides of the `custId` equation possibly being null. You will want to use a value that can't possibly be in your `custId` data, hence the negative number since most id's are positive.

```
IF EXISTS
 (SELECT
        1
  FROM
        myTable
  WHERE
        Id                     = @Id
        AND ISNULL(custId, -1) = ISNULL(@custId, -1))
BEGIN
    ...query
END;
```

Comment: Worked..!!! this also i have another solution i have share here OR condition this with if null value  like `IF (Select custId from myTable where Id=@Id) != @custId ) OR  (Select custId from myTable where Id=@Id AND CustId is null) BEGIN ....query END` but your logic is applicable for me.. so thank you so much brother...